# HTML Form not submitting data?

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit, splash-screen

I am trying to create a Splash page for my site Powered by Boonex dolphin but can't seem to get the login to work. (It just askes user to login again).

Here is the code.

```
<form id="login_box_form" action="member.php" method="post" onsubmit="validateLoginForm(this); return false;"
      class="form_advanced">
    <input class="form_input_hidden bx-def-font" type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="cV4xs5rYHF2=caQ68kyq"/>
    <input type="text" name="ID" value="Username" maxlength="20" class="default login" onclick="clearval('Username);"
           style="margin-right: 5px;"/>
    <input type="password" name="Password" value="Password" class="default login" onclick="clearval('Password');"/>
</form>
<a href="member.php" id="loginButton" class="sidebarButton floatLeft" onclick="document.login_box_form.submit();"><span>login</span></a>
```

Any ideas?

(live demo http://cometogethersupport.pro/splash.php)

Comment: FYI, looking at your demo with Firebug console, there's a few errors in there. You should look into fixing them first and see if it fixes your problems with login not working.

Comment: What does `validateLoginForm()` do?

Comment: remove the `return false` from the `onsubmit="validateLoginForm(this); return false;"` and tell us if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.login_box_form.submit()
```

should probably be

```
document.getElementById('login_box_form').submit()
```

From the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) console, here's what I see when I try both of those:

```
> document.login_box_form
  undefined
> document.getElementById('login_box_form');
  <form id=​"login_box_form" action=​"http:​/​/​cometogethersupport.pro/​member.php" method=​"post" onsubmit=​"validateLoginForm(this)​;​ return false;​" class=​"form_advanced">​…​</form>​
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the form ID get the form to submit(). either add an attribute to the form like this:

```
<form name="login_box_form"></form>
```

Or change your function call to:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('login_box_form').submit()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't help but notice this:

```
clearval('Username);
```

I can't help but ask you to change it! (Sorry!)

```
clearval('Username');
```

Also, why not try this, assuming this is where you're submitting the data to:

```
<form  id="login_box_form" action="http://cometogethersupport.pro/member.php" method="post" onsubmit="validateLoginForm(this); return false;" class="form_advanced">
```

P.S:

```
(2) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Line 99
```

Update JQuery?

Comment: Ok this may have been due to /inc/login.js wasn't linked correctly but I still have the issue. :(

Comment: @MichaelHoward what of `name="csrf_token" value="cV4xs5rYHF2=caQ68kyq"`?
Is that pre-set, or is that meant to change according to sessions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to fix this with the following code in the  tags:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function frmSubmit() {
document.login_box_form.submit();
}
</script>
```

Then set the Hyperlink to

```
javascript:frmSubmit();
```

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the `return false` from the `onSubmit` attribute of the `<form` tag?